SpreadSheet printing when it is not supposed to VBA Macros
I have been working on this VBA project for quite some time and I am quite close to getting it done, the VBA code is supposed to look at every sheet in the Excel document and look for the named ranges that:

First it looks for names that have total and their value is > 0, if they fulfill those 2 requisites, it adds the ws.name to sheetsArrayA and prints the sheet.
Second, it checks the sheets that are in the array A, and checks if they have a name that contains paytype and its value = "CHECK", if it does, it prints it again.

It prints all the correct sheets besides ML. I keep getting the ML Company to print once when it is not supposed to, the rest are good. they all contain a named range total and greater than 0, and some do have a paytype named range with its value = check, the ML company does not have a total, and therefore it is not greater than 0 either, the only thing it does have is a paytype that equals check, but that should not print it as total is more important). I do not why it is checking that sheet and its value when it does not have a total named range (not greater than 0 obviously) and it does have a paytype named range and equals check, but if it does not fullfill the first requirement, then it is supposed to ignore the paytype loop.
heres the code:
Option Explicit
Global Mark As Boolean, Unmark As Boolean, MagicPrint As Boolean

Sub PrintWorksheets()
    SpecialPrinting False, False, True
End Sub
Sub MarkWorksheets()
    SpecialPrinting True, False, False
End Sub
Sub UnmarkWorksheet()
    SpecialPrinting False, True, False
End Sub

Sub SpecialPrinting(Optional Mark As Boolean = False, Optional Unmark As Boolean = False, Optional MagicPrint As Boolean = False)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim SheetsArrayA(), SheetsArrayB()
    Dim i, j, sheetCount As Long
    Dim nm As Name
    Dim wsName As String
    Dim isInArrayA As Boolean
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim HomeSheet As Worksheet
    
    Set HomeSheet = ActiveSheet
    sheetCount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    
    ' Assign them as arrays.
    ReDim SheetsArrayA(1 To sheetCount)
    ReDim SheetsArrayB(1 To sheetCount)
    
    ' Array A
        On Error Resume Next
        For i = 1 To sheetCount
            wsName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name
            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)
            For Each nm In Names
                If Trim(Right(UCase(nm.Name), 5)) = "TOTAL" Then
                    SheetsArrayA(i) = ws.Name
                    
                    If MagicPrint And ThisWorkbook.Names(nm.Name).RefersToRange(1, 1) > 0 And _
                     GetWSName(nm) = ws.Name Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).PrintOut
                        Debug.Print "A: " & GetWSName(nm)
                    End If
                    
                    If Mark Then
                        With Worksheets(i).Range(nm).AddComment
                         .Visible = False
                         .Text "Total Field for Print Option: " & nm.Name
                        End With
                    End If
                    
                    If Unmark Then Worksheets(i).Range(nm).Comment.Delete
                End If
            Next nm
        Next i
    ' Array B
        For j = 1 To sheetCount
            x = 0
            x = WorksheetFunction.IfError(WorksheetFunction.Match(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(j).Name, SheetsArrayA, 0), 0)
            If x > 0 Then
                For Each nm In Names
                    If Trim(Right(UCase(nm.Name), 7)) = "PAYTYPE" Then
                             
                        If MagicPrint And UCase(ThisWorkbook.Names(nm.Name).RefersToRange(1, 1)) = "CHECK" And _
                         GetWSName(nm) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(x).Name Then
                            Debug.Print "Named Range: " & nm.Name
                            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(j).PrintOut
                            Debug.Print "B: " & GetWSName(nm)
                        End If
                
                        If Mark Then
                            With Worksheets(j).Range(nm).AddComment
                                .Visible = False
                                .Text "PayType Field for Print Option: " & nm.Name
                            End With
                        End If
                        
                        If Unmark Then Worksheets(j).Range(nm).Comment.Delete
                    End If
                Next nm
            End If
        Next j
        On Error GoTo 0
    HomeSheet.Activate
End Sub

Function GetWSName(wsData) As String
Dim s As Integer
Dim e As Integer
    If Left(wsData, 2) = "='" Then
        s = InStr(1, wsData, "'") + 1
        e = InStr(s, wsData, "'")
    Else
        s = 2
        e = InStr(2, wsData, "!")
    End If
    GetWSName = Mid(wsData, s, e - s)
End Function



Let's say ML Company is the second sheet. During the iteration where i=2, the For Each nm In Names loop goes through all the names. If any name satisfies the condition If Trim(Right(UCase(nm.Name), 5)) = "TOTAL" Then, ML Company is added to SheetsArrayA. ML Company is then printed in the next section.

Solution: Pls move SheetsArrayA(i) = ws.Name inside the If (before or after print the sheet).

btw, Avoid using On Error Resume Next unless you are certain that a specific error is being intentionally ignored.


' Array A
        ' On Error Resume Next
        For i = 1 To sheetCount
            wsName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name
            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)
            For Each nm In Names
                If Trim(Right(UCase(nm.Name), 5)) = "TOTAL" Then
                    ' SheetsArrayA(i) = ws.Name   ' ***
                    
                    If MagicPrint And ThisWorkbook.Names(nm.Name).RefersToRange(1, 1) > 0 And _
                     GetWSName(nm) = ws.Name Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).PrintOut
                        Debug.Print "A: " & GetWSName(nm)
                        SheetsArrayA(i) = ws.Name  ' ***
                    End If
                    
                    If Mark Then
                        With Worksheets(i).Range(nm).AddComment
                         .Visible = False
                         .Text "Total Field for Print Option: " & nm.Name
                        End With
                    End If
                    
                    If Unmark Then Worksheets(i).Range(nm).Comment.Delete
                End If
            Next nm
        Next i


thank you, that fixed the problem! can i ask, why changing the position of that line resulted in not printing ML anymore?

By moving the code line, only the sheets with a Total greater than 0 are added to the array SheetsArrayA.
